# DataGridView doesn't show data without select with pointer

Tags: c#, datagridview

My datagridview does not show any data even it has data. When I run the code, my output is just a table without data until I select rows with pointer.

I have searched about this case and one of the suggestions was to change the settings of **"columnheadersdefaultcellstyle"**. I have tried to solve with this way but it did not work. Also I changed background color of datagrid, as well.

What should I do to see data in the datagridview without select with pointer ?

Comment: Can you show the code you used to assign data to the DataGridView?

Comment: Thank you for answering :) I have solved the issue. I changed the color of **"ForeColor"** from **properties of Form**. I guess it was white and therefore table is not able to be seen. I could not answer my own question, so if someone could write the solution it might be  a way to other people who have same problem. Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go Minerva ;)

Changing the `ForeColor` property of the form to something other than white makes the data visible.